# Internal Web App: Do I need an API?

Tags: rest, meteor, web-applications, publish-subscribe

I'm creating a new web application for internal use at work with internal data, and have been exploring tech stack options. I've used a REST API for another internal web app (also using internal SQL Server data), but then I read this today at [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API)

> A common question is how to create a REST API with Meteor. First, it's critical to understand that if you are making an API for your own apps and tools, you've got it wrong! We hope it's very clear that between the server and client, you have a bidirectional DDP connection that handles realtime syncing of published data (see Publish and Subscribe in the docs).

**So it seems I've got it wrong!** I thought I needed an API to get data to my web app; that's what all the tutorials and articles seem to deal with. Where do I go to learn how else to do it? Or is this just something that Meteor offers and other front-end frameworks don't necessarily?

**EDIT: Some more details:** This app will be used by probably less than 10 people, the database is SQL Server. It won't be used on mobile, and the data doesn't need to be queried from elsewhere (it's sensitive data, so at the very least it would have to be an authenticated API).

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong, honestly i think making a good API is the cleanest way to work with your web app and your database

but yes it's not the only way. Depends of what you do with you web app

you don't NEED an API, but it's, I think the best way to do what you want

and yes I think it's a meteor offer

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the architecture and scalability of your project and what will do you. For example, you can have a BaaS Architecture (Backend at as Service) thats could be a Web Service or a REST API, if do you want scalibility and offer a service that for you not matter the device, you should develope a API with a BaaS Architecture. On the other hand, if do you want offer a whole ecosystem, with a iPhone app, Android app, Desktop app, you need a PaaS architecture (Platform as a Service) But, if do you want a simple web app (a monolithic app) You shouldn't thinking about on this and apply a simple MVC.

Remember: API -> Application Program Interface, this mean that if you need expose your data for a personal use (for example, make a Android App that consult your API) o maybe expose your services for Developers, you should make an API.

It's depends of what do you want.

1. [BaaS on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service)
2. [PaaS on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service)